# Get parent branch from pushed branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow which attempted to auto-create PR when changes pushed to the branches with prefix `subtask/*` or `bugfix/*`. Branches with such prefixes are always branched out from a branch like `story/*`, `task/*` or `production`.

When I am executing the following locally, I am able to get the parent branch name.

```
# Get the current branch name
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

# Determine the parent branch using your command
PARENT_BRANCH=$(git show-branch | sed "s/].*//" | grep "\*" | grep -v "${CURRENT_BRANCH}" | head -n1 | sed "s/^.*\[//")
```

Unfortunately, when it executes in GitHub Actions, `echo "PARENT_BRANCH=${PARENT_BRANCH}"` is printing empty value for `PARENT_BRANCH`.

```
name: Auto-create PR when changes pushed to subtask/* or bugfix/*

# This workflow create the following pull requests
# subtask/* or bugfix/* merge to parent branch
# when changes pushed to subtask/* or bugfix/* branch
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - subtask/*
      - bugfix/*

jobs:
  createPR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: {my-repo-name}
          token: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

      - name: Determine parent branch
        id: determine-parent-branch
        run: |
          # Get the current branch name
          CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

          # Determine the parent branch using your command
          PARENT_BRANCH=$(git show-branch | sed "s/].*//" | grep "\*" | grep -v "${CURRENT_BRANCH}" | head -n1 | sed "s/^.*\[//")

          echo "PARENT_BRANCH=${PARENT_BRANCH}"

      - name: Create pull request from ${{ github.ref_name }} to ${{ steps.determine-parent-branch.outputs.PARENT_BRANCH }}
        uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          pr_label: "automerge"
          pr_title: "Auto-PR from ${{ github.ref_name }} to ${{ steps.determine-parent-branch.outputs.PARENT_BRANCH }}"
          destination_branch: ${{ steps.determine-parent-branch.outputs.PARENT_BRANCH }}
```

Comment: Note `actions/checkout` is _shallow_ by default - [_"Only a single commit is fetched by default, for the ref/SHA that triggered the workflow. Set `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all history for all branches and tags."_](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v4)

Answer (score -2):

The reason why the `PARENT_BRANCH` variable is empty in your GitHub Actions workflow is because the `git show-branch` command does not work correctly in a GitHub Actions environment.

To fix this, you can use the following workaround:

```yaml
name: Auto-create PR when changes pushed to subtask/* or bugfix/*

This workflow create the following pull requests
subtask/* or bugfix/* merge to parent branch
when changes pushed to subtask/* or bugfix/* branch
on:
push:
branches:
- subtask/*
- bugfix/*

jobs:
createPR:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout repository
uses: actions/checkout@v3
with:
repository: {my-repo-name}
token: ${{ secrets.GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
- name: Determine parent branch
id: determine-parent-branch
run: |
# Get the current branch name
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

    # Get the parent commit hash
      PARENT_COMMIT_HASH=<span class="math-inline">\(git rev\-parse HEAD^\)

    # Get the parent branch name
    PARENT_BRANCH=(git branch --contains "PARENT COMMIT HASH"∣grep−v"{CURRENT_BRANCH}" | head -n1)


    echo "PARENT_BRANCH=${PARENT_BRANCH}"
      - name: Create pull request from ${{ github.ref_name }} to <span class="math-inline">\{\{ steps\.determine\-parent\-branch\.outputs\.PARENT\_BRANCH \}\}



uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2
This workaround uses the `git rev-parse HEAD^` command to get the parent commit hash, and then uses the `git branch --contains "{PARENT_COMMIT_HASH}"` command to get the parent branch name.
```

Once you have made this change, your GitHub Actions workflow should be able to successfully determine the parent branch name and create a pull request accordingly.

Comment: What (aside from breaking the indentation) did you change?

Comment: There are some HTML fragments floating around now?

Comment: Tested and attempted to amend to the following, not working either.

```
# Get the current branch name
          CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

          # Get the parent commit hash
          PARENT_COMMIT_HASH=$(git rev-parse HEAD^)

          # Get the parent branch name
          PARENT_BRANCH=$(git branch --contains ${PARENT_COMMIT_HASH} | grep -v ${CURRENT_BRANCH} | head -n1)
          echo "PARENT_BRANCH=${PARENT_BRANCH}"
```